# Why do I obtain different integrals for this function?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Consider trying to find the indefinite integral of $${1\over e^x+1}.$$

One way to go is to change the variable of integration. This can be done in two ways, viz.: (1) Take $u=e^x+1,$ which transforms the integral into $\int du/u(u-1).$ (2) On the other hand, if one takes $v=e^x,$ the integral transforms into $\int dv/v(v+1).$

This is apparently a contradiction. Could someone please show me where the problem is?

Comment: No it is not, the integrands equal. The integral boundaries transform different for $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @James Look at the denominators of the integrands again. You are missing a difference in sign.

Comment: Why would this be a contradiction? I don't see any.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If the integrands are equal, then it follows that $0=-1.$

Comment: No, it doesn't. Consider the following easier integral $\int x^2\,dx$. If we make the substitution $t=x+1, dt=dx$ we get instead $\int (t-1)^2\,dt$. Are you saying that there is a contradiction here also?

Comment: $1/v(v+1)=1/(e^x(1+e^x))$ and $1/u(u-1)=1/((e^x+1)(e^x))$

Comment: And don't forget that $+C$ in all formulas for **indefinite** integrals.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh, I forgot the condition $u=v+1.$

Comment: @James Thanks for that last comment of yours.

Comment: Thank you both. Your comments have made me see I left out a constraint.

Comment: Indeed, it seems what led me to this wrong conclusion was that I was taking $u=v,$ which is of course nonsense. I've been an idiot!